# Certificate not imported on azure with Federation Metadata XML

Tags: azure, acs, ws-federation

I have created a IDP and that supports WS-FED protocol. While configuring WS-FED IDP on Azure side using Metadata XML the token signing certificate is not imported. XML contains the certificate under the tag .

No error while importing the certificate. After importing the Metadata XML when the newly created IDP entity is opened there is no certificate.

I am using a Certificate signed by Internal CA.

Comment: Can you precicely describe what you mean by `While configuring WS-FED IDP on Azure side using Metadata XML` ?!

Comment: I am using CA SiteMinder as IDP. To create a Identity Provider on Azure I followed the link "Identity Providers" on Azure ACS management page. Selected Add on that page to add a new IDP. Uploaded the xml document from my IDP(CA Siteminder). and saved it.